# Python 2.7.11 in Visual Studio Throws Exception in cElementTree.py

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2015, celementtree

I'm coding Python in Visual Studio 2015 which has worked great for the past few days, however this morning I decided to move the solution and directory to a GitHub-monitored directory on my Windows machine. Ever since I moved the solution and run it in debug mode, it throws this message:

> un(shallow)copyable object of type `<type 'element'>`

I'm completely stumped because there's no class named **cElementTree.py** in my project; it's actually here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\2_7_11\Lib\xml\etree
```

I can run the code in the original location just fine, so something was messed up in transit. I've copied it multiple times and it keeps throwing that exception. How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "continue" option in the menu bar. It should run just fine, even if the location of the file has been changed.